# How to deal with Android Gradle files under source control?

Tags: android, git, gitignore

I'm having a source control issue where certain files keep getting changed after syncing the project with gradle.

Here's what typically happens

- I create a release branch.
- Gradle needs to sync so I sync it.
- These files have changes when observing them after the sync:

`git status`

```
modified:   app/build/generated/source/r/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java
modified:   app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/google/android/gms/R.java
modified:   app/build/generated/source/r/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R.java
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$color.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$drawable.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$id.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$layout.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$string.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/google/android/gms/R$color.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/google/android/gms/R$drawable.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/google/android/gms/R$string.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/Globals.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$color.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$dimen.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$drawable.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$id.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$integer.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$layout.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$menu.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$mipmap.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$raw.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$string.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$style.class
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/obfuscated/obfuscated/R$styleable.class
modified:   app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
modified:   app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt
```

I had communicated to the rest of my team to use this .gitignore:

```
#built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Windows thumbnail db
Thumbs.db

# OSX files
.DS_Store

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Android Studio
*.iws
*.iml
.idea
.gradle
build/
*/build/
```

**Question 1: Commit the above changes?**

These files all match `*/build/` specified in .gitignore so my instinct is to remove them from source control locally using `git rm`. Is that correct?

**Question 2: Is there an issue with removing the Manifest or the entire build folder?**
This one : `app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

Deleting the entire build folder (`git rm app/build -r -f`) and re-syncing creates this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Obfuscated/Projects/Android/Obfuscated/app/build/intermediates/exploded-a‌​ar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
```

**Question 3: How to organize the project and team properly?**

What do I need to do get the project organized properly? How will the rest of my team proceed as well?

Comment: Syntax for ignoring directories named 'build' at any depth is `**/build/`

Comment: are you saying to use `**/build` instead of `*/build`?

Comment: Yes, `**/build/` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

**Backup your files before trying.**

You have two problems.

1. You have build files and  *.class files committed/stored in your Git repository.
2. You may have an issue with your .gitignore file.

Solution to problem 1:

Delete the build folder. It is generated by the gradles.

The line from git status

```
deleted:    app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/v7/appcompat/R$color.class
```

is saying that the file is committed in the Git repository has been deleted on your working copy,  which is fine.  So, yes you do want to commit this 'delete'.

Solution to problem 2: 
After Step 1 the unwanted files are removed from he Git Repository.  Git Status will display a list of 'add' files.   Modify .gitignore file so they no longer are displayed on git status command.   Something like /build/**,  you'll need to tweak it.   As a rule no files in /build should be committed to the Git Repository

Repeat as necessary

As a general rule before any git add command consider if that is correct or if it should be included in the .gitignore

The Manifest file should be committed to the git repository.   But not the one in the build folder.

Comment: I followed your steps and then re-sync'd gradle. The project then no longer compiled giving this error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Obfuscated/Projects/Android/Obfuscated/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)`